# If $\int u\varphi = 0$ for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(M)$ with $\int_M \varphi =0$, is $u=0$ a.e.?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and $u \in L^2(M)$. we know that if for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(M)$, $$\int_M \varphi u = 0,$$ then $u=0$ a.e.

Suppose $$\int_M \varphi u =0$$ for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(M)$ with $\int_M \varphi =0$. Then does the conclusion still hold that $u=0$ a.e?

Comment: Does $u\in L^2(M)$ yet?

Comment: Yes, $u \in L^2(M)$ for the second equation too.

Comment: It seems the fundamental theorem of calculus of variations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, consider $u=1\mbox{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is affirmative if we consider $C_0$ and assume $u\in L^1_{loc}$. Weak derivative being zero implies $u$ has to be zero $a.e$ see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpantherfile.uwm.edu%2Fkevinm%2Fwww%2Fteaching%2F726%2Fweakderiv1d.pdf&ei=asURVNmPHMG0ggTF34KIDw&usg=AFQjCNFtXa4p3cHWPmaM79brwlk1PPfPSQ&bvm=bv.74894050,d.eXY&cad=rja)